# Parsing complex xml with simplexml

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have got this xml structure below. For every 'locatie' (in every 'land') I need the 'id' value and it's 'sneeuwkwaliteit'.

My effort so far, does not return the value of 'sneeuwkwaliteit':

```
$sneeuw = simplexml_load_file('ski.xml');
echo $sneeuw->land[0]->locaties[0]->sneeuw->{'ski'}->sneeuwkwaliteit;


<sneeuw> 
  <aanmaak_tijd>09-01-2016 07:48</aanmaak_tijd>  
  <landen> 
    <land id="Andorra"> 
      <locaties> 
        <locatie id="Arinsal/Pal"> 
          <ski> 
            <datum_tijd>09-01-2016</datum_tijd>  
            <sneeuwhoogte_dal>40</sneeuwhoogte_dal>  
            <sneeuwhoogte_berg>70</sneeuwhoogte_berg>  
            <sneeuwkwaliteit>De aanwezige sneeuw is poedersneeuw.</sneeuwkwaliteit>  
            <datum_laatste_sneeuwval>07-01-2016</datum_laatste_sneeuwval>  
            <hoeveelheid_laatste_sneeuwval>20</hoeveelheid_laatste_sneeuwval>  
            <totaal_aantal_liften>25</totaal_aantal_liften>  
            <aantal_liften_geopend>25</aantal_liften_geopend> 
          </ski> 
        </locatie> 
      </locaties> 
    </land> 
  </landen> 
</sneeuw>
```

Comment: try indenting your xml to see the structure better, maybe use `landen[0]` instead of `land[0]`. I don't know about php but if this was a json object I would traverse it like this:`sneeuw.landen[0].locaties[0].ski.sneeuwkwaliteit`

Comment: There is no implicit relationship between "landen" and "land" (they might as well ne "foo" and "bar"). You must address all levels: sneeuw.landen[0].land[0].locaties[0].locatie[0].ski[0].sneeuwkwaliteit. You May omit [0] where multiple entries are not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Just carefully follow the path from the root of your XML to the target element :

```
$xml = <<<XML
<sneeuw> 
  <aanmaak_tijd>09-01-2016 07:48</aanmaak_tijd>  
  <landen> 
    <land id="Andorra"> 
      <locaties> 
        <locatie id="Arinsal/Pal"> 
          <ski> 
            <datum_tijd>09-01-2016</datum_tijd>  
            <sneeuwhoogte_dal>40</sneeuwhoogte_dal>  
            <sneeuwhoogte_berg>70</sneeuwhoogte_berg>  
            <sneeuwkwaliteit>De aanwezige sneeuw is poedersneeuw.</sneeuwkwaliteit>  
            <datum_laatste_sneeuwval>07-01-2016</datum_laatste_sneeuwval>  
            <hoeveelheid_laatste_sneeuwval>20</hoeveelheid_laatste_sneeuwval>  
            <totaal_aantal_liften>25</totaal_aantal_liften>  
            <aantal_liften_geopend>25</aantal_liften_geopend> 
          </ski> 
        </locatie> 
      </locaties> 
    </land> 
  </landen> 
</sneeuw>
XML;
$sneeuw = simplexml_load_string($xml);
echo $sneeuw->landen[0]->land[0]->locaties[0]->locatie[0]->ski[0]->sneeuwkwaliteit;
```

**<kbd>[`eval.in demo`](https://eval.in/499901)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
De aanwezige sneeuw is poedersneeuw.
```

For more complex query against XML, look into [`XPath`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath), which has it's own specification. Then you can execute XPath expression using [`SimpleXMLElement::xpath()`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) function.

**UPDATE :**

You can use XPath, as mentioned above, to iterate through all `sneeuwkwaliteit` elements located in the same path :

```
....
$result = $sneeuw->xpath('/sneeuw/landen/land/locaties/locatie/ski/sneeuwkwaliteit');
foreach($result as $r){
    echo $r ."<br>";
}
```

Comment: That is great. Is it possible to make a for each loop as this is the first set only (0).